# APIError(code=-1100): Illegal characters found in parameter 'symbol'; legal range is '^[A-Z0-9-_.]{1,20}$'

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

```
import binancekeys
from binance.client import Client
from datetime import datetime
from twisted.internet import reactor
import pandas as pd

client = Client(binancekeys.api_key, binancekeys.api_secret, tld='com')
moedas = ['ETCUSDT', 'ADAUSDT', 'USDTBRL', 'BTCUSDT']
tickers = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=(['moedas']))
histo = client.get_historical_klines(tickers['symbol'], Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "5 minute ago UTC")

df = pd.DataFrame(histo)

tabela = df.set_axis(['Time', 'Open', 'High','Low','Close','Volume','Close Time','Asset Volume','Number Of Trades','Buy Bae,','Buy Quote','Ignore'], axis=1)

print(tabela)
```

When i execute this script i have received this error:
APIError(code=-1100): Illegal characters found in parameter 'symbol'; legal range is '^[A-Z0-9-_.]{1,20}$' - any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because you are calling `get_symbol_tickers()` with a list (instead of a single symbol, have a look at the documentation [documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#symbol-price-ticker)).

If you want more than one symbol, I recommend to call `get_symbol_tickers()` without specifying any symbols, and then filter the desired symbols in a further step.

Below, you find a possible solution for your problem:

```py
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd

# Selection of symbols
moedas = ['ETCUSDT', 'ADAUSDT', 'USDTBRL', 'BTCUSDT']

# Initialize client, no key or secret needed.
client = Client()

# Get all tickers and keep only the ones in moedas list
r = client.get_symbol_ticker()
tickers = {i['symbol']: i['price'] for i in r if i['symbol'] in moedas}

# Create empty dict and get klines in iteration
columns = [
    'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Close Time', 'Asset Volume',
    'Number Of Trades', 'Buy Base', 'Buy Quote', 'Ignore',
]
klines = {}
for symbol in moedas:
    r_klines = client.get_historical_klines(
        symbol, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE,
        "5 minute ago UTC"
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(r_klines, columns=columns)
    klines[symbol] = df
```

This will return the variable `klines` as `dict` with the symbols of `moedas` as key and the kline dataframe as value (I'm not sure, if this is the output you are looking for).